# DE Special Character when importing from a CSV

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, data-import

I've been importing data from CSV - excel pages register as DOC CSV in the rolling menu. Except it doesn't take into accoung my special character (much needed in french words). I tried changing them in the notepad but still importing as this.

Does anyone as a tip to import accents into the marketing cloud DE from excel?

[image: Exemple of an accent bug]

Comment: Is this a salesforce core or marketing cloud question?

Comment: Marketing Cloud

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your source data file might not be encoded properly,

from the H&T portal, [Why isn’t Data Loader importing special characters?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_import_dataloader_specialchars.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

> 1. Make any modifications to your source data file in .xls format.
> 2. In Microsoft® Excel®, save a copy of your file as a Unicode Text
>      file.
> 3. Open the Unicode Text file you just saved with a text editor.
> 4. Click File | Save As to change the following file settings:
>
>    -File name extension—.csv
>
>    -Save as type—All Files
>
>    -Encoding—UTF-8
> 5. Click Save, and close the file.

Comment: This marketing marketing cloud?

Comment: I've also had success encoding the csv file as UTF-8 using a text editor like Notepad++, Sublime, or UltraEdit.